# Ubuntu blank screen after login

Tags: server, gnome, login

I login to my ubuntu via command line and it is ok. However, via GUI it shows me a blank screen after the login. I tried many solution which did not work:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config.old
mv ~/.local ~/.local.old
mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.old
```

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3 ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell
sudo systemctl reboot
```

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo reboot
```

My Ubuntu is an ubuntu server 20.04 which I installed GUI on it.

I am not after trying another random solution. I prefer steps to find the rout cause before applying the solution.

---

update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who faced with similar problem.

I switched to Wayland by clicking on the gear on desktop. Then did a login. It logins fine and displays the desktop. Then, I removed many files on home directory (not sure if they really had any impact). Then restarted. Then logged in via gnome and it worked fine.